# Pattern substitution in a makefile: create `A/libA.o B/libB.o C/libC.o` from `A B C`

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I am writing a makefile. I have got a word list `A B C`.

I would like to transform this into a list `A/libA.o B/libB.o C/libC.o`.

How can I do that?

I have tried the `patsubst` (see [manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Text-Functions.html)). However, its functionality seems to be too restricted for this task.

Answer (score 1):

Easy enough; you want to use [the `foreach` function](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Foreach-Function.html):

```
LIST = A B C
NEW = $(foreach L,$(LIST),$L/lib$L.o)
```